# Can MongoDB mess up data once it's in the DB

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I am using MongoDB with the Morphia Object-2-Document mapping library. I was under the impression that Morphia uses "Journal" mode and therefore uses transactions to store/retrieve data - implying that reliability shouldn't be a problem.

I never had any issues before but one field (for all documents) has this nonsense value ••••• . When I look in the DB it looks empty.

Is this something that Mongo might do to my data, or do I need to look elsewhere for the problem.

Comment: If it had a bug that major, it would have been fixed (or at least well known).  Likely it's you messing up the data, not MongoDB.  I wouldn't imagine it would do any kind of transformations to data once it's stored.

Comment: @Corbin :) good point. I'm relieved.

Comment: I should probably point out though that my experience with MongoDB consists of about 30 minutes of "ooo this is nifty" style playing with it.  For all I know, it may actually transform data.  But, as Boosty said, DBs are designed to store data, not ruin it.  (Not exactly what he said, but general gist :))

Answer (score 2):

Databases are made to store data, not to alter them when inserting. So it's most probably not mongoDB.

Nonsense values in databases usually have something to do with character encoding. Check if your encoding is the same for your application and the mongoDB database.

Comment: Thanks Boosty. However is it possible that Mongo "moves data around", and that "things can go wrong" when that happens. I know that's a vague question and if it's unanswerable don't worry. Anyway I really hope it's not MongoDB, it works so well.

Comment: Something can always go wrong, ofcourse, but mongoDB is a pretty mature product already and is tested extensivly. Something relativly simple like moving data internally probably works correctly. (I say probably a lot, as I don't know anything of the development of mongoDB)

Answer (score 2):

> I was under the impression that Morphia uses "Journal" mode and therefore uses transactions to store/retrieve data - implying that reliability shouldn't be a problem

"Journal" mode would refer to Morphia modifying MongoDB and waiting until MongoDB had written that data to the journal before returning.

MongoDB performs atomic updates on individual documents. However, it does not support transactions. So if you save a Morphia object that has three different collections underneath, there is no "start transaction" or "rollback" going on here.

> I never had any issues before but one field (for all documents) has this nonsense value...

That typically involves either Binary data or incorrectly encoded string (depends on where you are seeing the non-sense data). Bad data in MongoDB will throw exceptions, so MongoDB clearly believes it has correct data.

Comment: Thanks for this. "Bad data in MongoDB will throw exceptions, so MongoDB clearly believes it has correct data." This will be useful to remember.